# Elasticsearch filtering nested object

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a simplified object that looks something like this:

```
"name" : "Partner Name",
"features" : [ 
    {
        "val" : "Family",
        "key" : "Type"
    },
    {
        "val" : "Paris",
        "key" : "City"
    }
],
"variants" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Activity 1 Name",
        "description" : "Quick description",
        "price" : 20
    }
]
```

I want to filter by the City and Type keys. My current query filters by price but I can't get it working for City or Type. Adding more terms to the filter array didn't do the trick.

```
'query':{
    'filtered':{
        'query':{
            'query_string':{
                'query':query
            }
        },
    'filter': {
        'bool':{
            'filter': [{ 
                    'range': {
                        'variants.price': {
                            'gte': 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                { 
                    'range': {
                        'variants.price': {
                            'lte': 50
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    'term': {
                        'active': true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I wish there was lengthy documentation on writing queries like this.
Spending hours swimming through a variety of suggestions on stack overflow sucks. Especially when over half the accepted answers are invalid due to version breaking changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "range": {
                "variants.price": {
                  "gte": 0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "variants.price": {
                  "lte": 50
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "features",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": [
                      {"term":{"features.key":"type"}},
                      {"term":{"features.key":"city"}}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried formatting the JSON like you suggested but I'm still getting a 400 bad response error. Here's the pastebin of my object http://pastebin.com/nsex7PfK

Comment: What ES version are you using?

Comment: Elasticsearch 2.3.4

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm not inserting my documents correctly. I'm using the bulk API and included type:'nested' but when using the Sense chrome plugin to search I'm getting the error "[nested] nested object under path [features] is not of nested type"

Comment: You need to create the index upfront. And to give it your own mapping definition. At least for the fields that are `nested`. Otherwise ES will not know that you want `nested` fields.

Comment: I can't provide the mapping as I bulk insert documents?

Comment: No. You need to manually create that index with your own mapping as I mentioned before. Or, if this is an index that gets created periodically (daily, weekly, monthly) you could create an index template that can create the index automatically when the new documents are indexed for the first time.

Comment: I'm using the AngularJS client. Which API method should I use for creating the mappings?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AngularJS es clients. I'd start looking at this first: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/browser-builds.html#_angular_build

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll mark your answer as the right one since it probably works if I have my mapping set up correctly.

Comment: I added the mapping and the error is gone but your query doesn't return any results. Even filtering only on variants.price, which was working before, doesn't return anything.

Comment: What's the exact query that you are running and not working?

Comment: Here's the query http://pastebin.com/C5fbsjcc 

It's supposed to return 1 result.

Comment: The issue was I was searching for "Toronto" instead of lowercase "toronto". It works now but filtering on a phrase that contains 2 words returns 0 results.

Comment: Well... yeah, that's a longer story. `term` filter is not doing anything to the text to be searched. At the opposite side there is `match` which is analyzing the text to be searched. You noticed probably that my query is using lowercase text everywhere. The reason is that by default the `standard` analyzer is used at indexing time (which among others is lowercasing).